# Strang's Introduction to Linear Algebra (2016 5th edition), section 4.3, question 14, page 230

Tags: linear-algebra

> 14. Second assumption behind least squares: The $m$ errors $e_i$ are independent with variance $\sigma^2$, so the average of $(b - Ax)(b - Ax)^T$ is $\sigma^2I$. Multiply on the left by $(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$ and on the right by $A(A^TA)^{-1}$ to show that the average matrix $(\hat{x} - x)(\hat{x} - x)^T$ is $\sigma^2(A^TA)^{-1}$. This is the ***covariance matrix*** $W$ in Section 10.2.

I understand how to compute the result as what it is on the solution but I can't understand a condition held in the description that "the average of $(b - Ax)(b - Ax)^T$ is $\sigma^2I$". I know $b - Ax$ would produce the vector of errors but I don't know why their outer product can produce a diagonal matrix such as $\sigma^2I$. Can anyone explain to me how this relation is obtained?

Answer (score 1):

Let $e = b - Ax$ denote the vector of errors. The equation $ee^T = \sigma^2 I$ is a convenient way of encapsulating the assumption that the errors are independent with identical variance $\sigma^2$. That is, $ee^T = \sigma^2 I$ is equivalent to saying that the components $e_1,\dots,e_m$ of $e$ satisfy
$$
\overline{e_i e_j} = \begin{cases}
\sigma^2 & i=j\\
0 & i \neq j,
\end{cases}
$$
where $\bar x$ denotes the average value of $x$.

Comment: So what you mean is that assuming the vector e orthogonal to itself which is equally to say they are independent. So that their resultant matrix by their outer product is a diagonal matrix whose main diagonal is filled in with e^2. But I am still not convinced since I rarely see this in the real cases and how come every entry of the main diagonal is \sigma^2 instead of e^2?

Comment: @oscarmetalbreak Where are you getting "the vector e orthogonal to itself"? I don't know what you're trying to convey with that phrase

Comment: Since the only case I know for the outer product that produces diagonal matrix is orthogonal matrix? I still don't know why e_i*e_j if i not equal to j can be 0 or sigma^2. Could you give me an example?

Comment: @oscarmetalbreak I think there is a miscommunication here. When he says "the average of $(Ax - b)(Ax - b)^T$", I assumed that he was talking about the average of a probability distribution. However, based on the fact that you are treating $e$ as a matrix instead of as a random variable, perhaps you are trying to say that "the average of $(Ax - b)(Ax - b)^T$" refers to the average of finitely many measurments

Comment: Yes, that may be something I me struggling with because e in my thought is a n by 1 matrix or vector and the outer product of itself created a n by n matrix which in my opinion is unlikely a diagonal matrix.